# Can't enter a method in debugging mode in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, intellij-idea

In debugging mode, once I finish the debugging in one method, and need to return to the caller, the program gets stuck because it enters into the logic of external library's code, i.e. spring framework's MethodProxy, as shown in the screenshot, and I can't continue to get into my own code. 'stuck' means that it goes into the spring frameworks's code, i.e. MethodProxy, not my own code, the caller of my method.

Likewise, if my debugging logic tries to enter another method, it enters spring frameworks' code, i.e. CglibAopProxy. I am not aware of what caused this. I have been able to debug my code in the past, but don't know why and how this happened.

I am developing in Spring-boot and using IntelliJ IDE.

When I tried to debug into a method, this happened:

[image]

And when I tried to return to the caller, this happened:

[image]

Comment: What means program stuck? You are setting new breakpoint and it doesn't stop there?

Comment: @ArtemPetrov, please see my updated. It turned out that it has nothing to do with multiple threading.

Answer (score 5):

You can setup stepping filters so that debugger do not stop there while stepping.

For example you can add `org.springframework.*`:

[image: stepping filters]
There's [IDEA-143338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143338) and several related issues to have this for spring packages out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

For spring it is absolutely normal to create proxy object for user's beans (for instance to managed transactions). Hence it is absolutely normal to have situation when your seems to be calling from your class method to another your class but in-between actually will be executed some other code.

If you what to continue debug from place where your code invoked method you are debugging right now the simplest way for me would be to put breakpoint in your caller method after the call line.

Example:

You have an application:

```
package pkg;

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
    }
}

@Component
class MyTask implements ApplicationRunner {
    private final MyRepository repository;

    public MyTask(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        repository.doIt();
        System.out.println("........");
    }
}

@Repository
class MyRepository {
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
}
```

And you happen to debug `MyRepository.doIt` method.

[image]

If you what to go to your caller method (but don't know where it was called) inspect Frames in debug window

[image]

There you can find call stack and choose from where you what to continue debugging your application. (Libraries code usually highlighted with yellow)

Then just put breakpoint to the next line after current method invocation and press F9 (Resume Program)

[image]

Optionally you can just put cursor on required row and press 'Run to cursor' (Alt+F9 or Option+F9)